# Overwrite existing LED notification

Tags: android, notifications

I cast an LED notification this straight forward way:

```
NotificationManager notifMgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
notifMgr.cancelAll();
Notification notif = new Notification();
notif.ledARGB = 0xff0000ff; 
notif.ledOnMS = 99999; 
notif.ledOffMS = 0; 
notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
notifMgr.notify(1234, notif);
```

It let the LED just permanent light blue.
If, in that state, I receive for example a google talk message, it's notification overwrites my LED state, so the LED now blinks white (gtalk default).
If now my program creates another LED notification, for some reason it does not overwrite the gtalk LED notification, so the LED stays blinking white.

How can I make my notification overwrite other LED notivications? Obviously there must be a way, since gtalk overwrites my LED state.

Thank you!

Comment: You should not be assuming *any* behavior on the part of the device when you ask for LEDs on your `Notification`. Some devices do not have LEDs. Some device manufacturers may not allocate an LED to `Notifications`. Some device manufacturers may favor firmware (charging status, chat applications, etc.) over SDK apps. And so on.

Comment: But at least the program "lightflow" seems to be able to do it

Answer (score 1):

Whichever app raises the notification first keeps control of the led until it's cleared by that app or the user clearing it.

You description sounds incorrect of gtalk overriding your notification if yours is currently on. I know a little about this as I'm the author of "lightflow"